# Javascript water ripple effect slowdown in framerate

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written a super simple javascript to create a water ripple effect for a website, and the illusion if fairly effective, but I am having some issue with my timer lagging from numerous instances. Originally I attempted it using some CSS3 effects to acheive, but the computer rendering the elements would freeze the screen after a while, so I rewrote it to alter a single PNG repeatedly, and this helped quite a bit, but still gets bogged down. I am not sure how to improve this issue, if using some preload might help (doubt that) or if there is some other optimization which could fix what is a very promising start.

here is my code:

```
body{
    background-color:#444;
    position:absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index:0;}
.circle{
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(circle5.png);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:2;}
```

and the javascript

```
var locX = '';
var checkX = '';
var locY = '';
var checkY = '';
var eventTimer = setInterval(function(){changeCs()}, 1);//'FRAMERATE' of state changes in milliseconds

//Listen for user mouse movement, fetch current location of cursor, initiate droplets
document.onmousemove = function(e){
    var event = e || window.event;
    locX = event.clientX;
    locY = event.clientY;
    createC();}

//We create divs with the circular image stretched to the otherwise blank div   
function createC(){
//Check to see if the X and Y are the same as in previous cycle, if so movement has stopped.
  if(parseInt(locX) != parseInt(checkX) && parseInt(locY) != parseInt(checkY)){
    var n_Circle = document.createElement('div');
    n_Circle.setAttribute('class','circle');
    n_Circle.setAttribute('style','width:10px;height:3px;opacity:.4;');
    document.body.appendChild(n_Circle);
//We obtain the coordinates of the cursor, and use the same X as the user.
//However with the Y we are shifting downward from the top to maintain illusion of water surface -*THINK EYE LEVEL*
    n_Circle.style.top = parseInt(.75 * window.innerHeight) + parseInt(locY * .4) + 'px';
    n_Circle.style.left = parseInt(locX) + 'px';
    window.setTimeout(function(){createC()},parseInt(Math.random() * 200 + 100));
  }else{return;}//EXIT Function loop
  //ASSIGN new check values before end ot the cycle
  checkX = locX;
  checkY = locY;

  }
//We manipulate the droplet images by this quantity every 'frame'
function changeCs(){
    var arrayCs = document.getElementsByClassName('circle');
    for(i=0; i < arrayCs.length; i++){
        arrayCs[i].style.width = parseInt(arrayCs[i].style.width) + 100 + 'px';
        arrayCs[i].style.left = parseInt(arrayCs[i].style.left) - 50 + 'px';
//The ratio of expansion does not match to the images aspect ratio.
//This helps to create the illusion of depth to the surface deformation
//by shearing a portion of the ellipse away, conveying a sense of depth and angularity
        arrayCs[i].style.height = parseInt(arrayCs[i].style.height) + 26 + 'px'; 
        arrayCs[i].style.top = parseInt(arrayCs[i].style.top) - 14 + 'px';
        arrayCs[i].style.opacity = arrayCs[i].style.opacity - .01;
        if(arrayCs[i].style.opacity <= .00){
            document.body.removeChild(arrayCs[i]);}}}
```

Will get a JSFiddle up pronto. Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QNf4K/ an example of the effect.

Comment: Another note, I had also previously attempted to use CSS transitions, but this seemed to lock up my browser almost immediately. It seems that any heavy-handed css use = browser freeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this makes a difference, to me it seems faster but its hard to tell as I'm not as nuanced to what your expectations are. fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/QNf4K/4/

Instead of creating a div element everytime I just created it once, then cloned it.
And I cached the length.

```
    var locX = '';
    var checkX = '';
    var locY = '';
    var checkY = '';
    var eventTimer = setInterval(function(){changeCs()}, 1);//'FRAMERATE' of state changes in milliseconds
    var ln_Circle = document.createElement('div');
        ln_Circle.setAttribute('class','circle');
        ln_Circle.setAttribute('style','width:10px;height:3px;opacity:.4;');

  //  then just cloned it here:
    var n_Circle = ln_Circle.cloneNode(true);

 //   I also cached the length here:


            var l = arrayCs.length, i = 0;
            for(; i < l; i++){
```

//   Then added a test for existence of arrayCs[i]

```
          if( arrayCs[i]){
            arrayCs[i].style.width = parseInt(arrayCs[i].style.width) + 100 + 'px';
```

Comment: Brilliant. Seems to have made a very significant increase in the framerate and smoothness on multiple renders. I am not sure that I understand the test on the arrayCs though.

Comment: also with  "for(; i < l; i++){" is this a typo or proper contextual use? I have not encountered this anywherebefore, but still pretty greenwith javascript.

Comment: Hey - I am glad it helped ( if you like it, you can accept as answer :-), trying to build rep ).. The "for" loop is just shorthand, and is valid. I put the "if" statement because in my console it was generating undefined moving thru that code. Maybe it was an anomoly. I put it there as a precaution, perhaps you don't need it. Again, I am glad it helped.

Comment: Also wondering now, when caching the arrayCs.length, is this essentially creating a string of the object and its properties?

Comment: hey - every time you reiterate over the loop, you are calling the method ".length" on the collection. That is a call you are making for each reiteration. So it is overhead since the collection size does not change. That is why I cache it, so the loop does not have to make that "length" call each time. I am only caching "its" length, nothing more. You are referencing the object properties with the "i" reference ie.. arrayCs[i].

Comment: I think I understand now, I was creating a bottleneck of resources checking the count for .length, so on multiple iterations the checks to the array length were significantly dragging the performance down, right? Much thanks again for the feedback.